# How to make a bold font in LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I use Overleaf for my graduation research, I tried to bold the font of the topic and the important points but I couldn't. I have no idea if it's because the font (Times New Roman) or what but I tried all the solutions.

Comment: Please show your current attempt

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] to your question. The answer might depend on your class, packages and in which context you try to have bold text.